# Parallel test execution in thucydides

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, batch-processing, thucydides

How do you execute parallel tests in thucydides ? 
I've tried setting Dthucydides.batch.count ( and Dthucydides.batch.size because someone mentioned that count is now size?), Dthucydides.batch.number, putting the  tag in the failsafe plugin in the .pom of my project, using the fork options in the maven failsafe plugin, but nothing works. It keeps executing tests one after another.

the mvn plugin i'm using to execute the tests as requested:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/When*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: 1) can you add your pom.xml? 2) how do you execute tests? 3) running Thucydides tests in parallel batches works only for JUnit  and easyb

Comment: I added the pom.xml, i am executing tests with mvn clean verify, and all my thucydides tests extend ThucydidesJUnitStory

Comment: Did you try to run it as `mvn verify -Dthucydides.batch.count=3 -Dthucydides.batch.number=1` like described in http://thucydides.info/docs/thucydides/_running_thucydides_tests_in_parallel_batches.html ?

Comment: Yes i did. They still execute one after another.

Comment: Wait, you run single batch from command line. Right? But tests in batch are executed one after other. AFAIK, batch strategy allows us to run batches in parallel.

Comment: Isn't -Dthucydides.batch.count=3 supposed to split the scenarios in 3 batches or am i mistaken ? If that's the case and i need to do something else to run the batches in parallel, what is it ?

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. According to http://thucydides.info/docs/thucydides/_running_thucydides_tests_in_parallel_batches.html `the following will divide the test cases into 3 batches (thucydides.batch.count), and only run the first test in each batch (thucydides.batch.number):mvn verify -Dthucydides.batch.count=3 -Dthucydides.batch.number=1`. Emphasis on `only run the first test in each batch`

Comment: Yeah i know, but it just isn't doing it